# Checking if a checkbox is checked using JQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this problem where I grabbed an open source on off button from the internet here is the code for that (it uses a checkbox)

HTML:

```
 <tr>
     <td class="td-actions"> 
         Alert 1
     </td>          
     <td class="td-actions"> 
         <div class="onoffswitch1">
             <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox1" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
             <label class="onoffswitch-label1" for="myonoffswitch1">
                 <span class="onoffswitch-inner1"></span>
                 <span class="onoffswitch-switch1"></span>
             </label>
         </div>
     </td>                          
 </tr>
```

The jQuery I am trying to use to see if its checked or not checked:

```
$("#myonoffswitch1").click(function () {
    alert($("#myonoffswitch1").prop("checked"));
});
```

Can anyone see why this is not working?

If you need to see the CSS for this let me know I dont think its necessary though.

The alert I believe should come back with a true or false but when I click the button it simply just does not do anything.

Comment: "Can anyone see why this is not working" what isn't working? what are you not getting that you'd expect?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/khL4bnjo/ seems to be working fine

Comment: @RajdeepDosanjh you beat me to it :P  - http://jsfiddle.net/9zvp46bz/ Works for me as well.

Comment: In the above text I said "so the alert I believe should come back with a true or false but when I click the button it simply just does not do anything."

Comment: @AlexWinter You either didn't include jQuery, or you are running this code before the element was loaded in the DOM.

Comment: @SLoW Your name says enough why he beat you :-)

Comment: Works for me too. Your script probably isn't running at all due to jQuery not being loaded, or trying to run it before the page is ready (try moving your script to right before the closing </body> tag. Look for any javascript errors in your web browser's error console.

Comment: According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is true of all boolean attributes.

Comment: [link](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) Another solution could be the browser, try to tick the checkbox in the demo in this case you could use `is(':checked')`

Comment: As Spencer Wieczorek said, your code is probably loaded before your html or the jquery libraries are not included. Try moving your js to the bottom if it's inline (in the html file)

Answer (score 1):

You should try LiveValidation 1.3 from www.livevalidation.com, i think you need some more function in js to chek the chek box. I dont have much expirience in Javascript but i was working on this a few times. I hope this helps you.

Comment: No, more functions are not needed to *check* the check box. I also don't see how LiveValidation is at all related, it does not appear that the OP is doing any form validation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `is()` function with ':checked' selector like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myonoffswitch1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
           alert('checked');
        else alert('unchecked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm nope this does not work, it seems like the jqeury isnt even getting executed at all. but im not sure why it isnt

Comment: As already said in the comments, the OP's code works fine (when things are loaded correctly). The problem is what I said above, jQuery not loaded or element is not loaded before running the code.

Comment: Spencer how do I fix this because I am using laravel and I have the code where it is supposed to be. I checked the network as well as in debuggin in google chrome and everything is loading fine it seems all 304 and 200 statuses

Comment: @AlexWinter I'm not saying something isn't loading correctly, I mean that at the time that the code ran something was not yet loaded (*and probably will be loaded later*) Add jQuery in the `<head>` tag and wrap your code in a `document.ready` function like in this answer: `$(function(){ ... });`, but you don't need to change your code.

Comment: Good point Spencer I will try that when i get home later I think that will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this is as Spencer said in a comment needed to wrap my .click function in a .ready here is the code which now works:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myonoffswitch1").click(function () {
            alert($("#myonoffswitch1").prop("checked"));
        });
    } 
);
```

Thanks Spencer! :)